# Possibility of evaluating the expression within a NestList at each iteration?

Tags: graphics, function-construction

I want to rotate iteratively a triangle about the same point, increasing for each iteration the length of its side in the same proportion and change the color of its sides.
I came up with the solution below:

```
triangle[x_] := 
Line[ {{0, 0}, {1 + x, 0}, {(1 + x)/2, (Sqrt[3] (1 + x)/2)}, {0, 0}}]
randomcolor[] := Apply[RGBColor, RandomReal[1, {3}]]
Show[Array[Graphics[Rotate[{Thick, randomcolor[], triangle[#]}, # (Pi/5), {0, 
  0}]] &, 3]]       (* a simple output *)
Show[Array[Graphics[Rotate[{Thick, randomcolor[], triangle[#]}, # (Pi/9), {0, 
  0}]] &, 180]]   (* more elaborated *)
```

There are certainly other and better ways to achieve this result. However my first attempt for my solution was to use NestList which I felt to be more suitable but could not proceed further than this line:

```
rot[gr_] := Rotate[gr, Pi/16, {0, 0}]
Graphics[{NestList[rot, triangle[#], #]}] & [2]
```

The same figure is repeated which is as expected there but is there any way at the start of each iteration to re-evaluate the value of the function triangle[#] with the current value of the Nestlist iterator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need an iterator you can do something like:

`i=0;` and put somewhere `i++` but it will not be straightforward with functions you have. You can use `FoldList` too, e.g:

```
Graphics @ Rest @ FoldList[
                    Rotate[{Hue[#2/10], triangle[#2]}, #2 Pi/16, {0, 0}] &,
                    1, 
                    Range[2, 10]]
```

[image]

Or another approach, with `NestList` but also with `Scale` since you want the ratio to be constant:

```
tri = Line[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, Sqrt[3]/2}, {0, 0}}]
p0 = {0, 0};
ratio = 1.05;
angle = Pi/8;
i = 25;

Graphics[
 NestList[
  {Hue@RandomReal[], Rotate[Scale[#[[2]], ratio, p0], angle, p0]} &,
  {Hue@RandomReal[], tri},
  i]
, PlotRange -> 5, BaseStyle -> Thick]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.Clever use of Rest and Scale was up to your answer unknown to me.

Comment: @SigismondKmiecik Great you find it useful :), good luck.