# How can I draw a square root spiral?

Tags: graphics, programming

I found this picture on the net.

[image]

How can I reproduce it in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Have you attempted to make this yourself? Do so, post code if you have problems or questions.

Comment: This should get you started: [(13894715)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13894715/) -- if you run into trouble let us know.

Comment: @Rahul I totally agree as I have seen that post before too!

Answer (score 21):

I appreciate that attempts should be the minimum standard. As this does not resemble the desired result, perhaps it can be a starting point. I look forward to OP attempt and other answers.

```
f[n_, d_] := Module[{r = Range@n, a},
  a = Sqrt[#]/d & /@ r;
  MapThread[#1 {-Cos[#2], -Sin[#2]} &, {Sqrt[r], a}]]
di[n_, d_, rad_] := Module[{fu, pt, grad, pg},
  fu = f[n, d];
  pt = MapIndexed[{White, EdgeForm[Black], Disk[#1, rad], 
      Text[Style[Sqrt[ToString[First@#2]], Black], #1]} &, fu];
  grad = Reverse[{{0, 0}, ##} & @@@ Partition[fu, 2, 1]];
  pg = MapIndexed[{Hue[First@#2/n], EdgeForm[Black], Polygon@#1} &, 
    grad];
  Graphics[Join[pg, pt]]
  ]
```

After some play:

```
di[87, 0.4, 0.5]
```

[image]

Comment: Lol- before I scrolled down to see name, *knew* this was your work just from the image... +1

Comment: @rasher I guess I am predictable but play is both instructive and therapeutic :)

Comment: @rasher thanks for your good humor and sorry if my 'tropic thunder' extension of commentary was more than the lame participation I intended it to be :)

Comment: Huh? I thought it hilarious! And the reason I knew this post was you is the quality of the graphic - I'd +1 again if I could...

Comment: @rasher...just feeling sorry for myself...working ten days straight starting to warp my head...I really enjoy the delights of MSE and the creativity and humor just wanted reality check...so thanks...back to salt mines

Answer (score 13):

I tried to do this without looking at the previous answers... let me know if I accidentally plagiarized!

```
With[{n = 87}, 
 Module[{radii = Sqrt[Range[n]], angles, coords}, 
  angles = Accumulate @ Most[ArcCot[radii]] ~Prepend~ 0; 
  coords = radii * Transpose @ Through[{Cos, Sin}[angles]];
  Graphics[{
    EdgeForm[Black], 
    Reverse @ MapIndexed[{
       FaceForm @ Blend[{White, RGBColor[.6, .7, 0], RGBColor[0, .2, 0]}, First@#2/n],
       Polygon[#1 ~Append~ {0, 0}]
     } &, Partition[coords, 2, 1]
    ],
    FaceForm[White], 
    MapIndexed[{
       Disk[#1, 1/3], 
       Text[Sqrt[ToString @ First[#2]], #1]
     } &, coords
    ]
  }, ImageSize -> Full]
 ]
]
```

[image]

I only spent about 15 minutes on this, but I think that this and the original have the correct angles, and that ubpdqn's is wrong...

P.S. I got my colors from:

```
Graphics3D[{RGBColor @@ #, Point@#} & /@ 
  First /@ Take[
    SortBy[Tally[
      Join @@ ImageData[
        Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYcLD.png"]]], Last], -100]]
```

Comment: I really wish that MMA had the ability to set font size in graphics coordinate units....

Comment: This does indeed match the question and probably should be accepted answer +1 and I should have thought a little better than I did wrt angles...so nice accumulation :)

Comment: @ubpdqn The point of the diagram is that each of the triangles is a right triangle.  If a given triangle has a length $\sqrt{n}$ leg and a length $1$ leg, the hypotenuse is $\sqrt{\sqrt{n}^2+1^2}=\sqrt{n+1}$.  The angle of each triangle is $\tan\theta=1/\sqrt{n}$, so $\theta=\text{arccot}\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @ubpdqn You did guess the form of the angle correctly though: see `Series[Integrate[ArcCot[Sqrt[m]], {m, 0, n}, 
  Assumptions -> n > 1], {n, \[Infinity], 0}]`.  The angle is about equal to $2\sqrt{n}$, so `di[_, 0.5, 0.5]` is pretty close to the original.

Comment: nice stealing from the OP's colour palette !

Comment: @chris I read "reproduce" as "reproduce exactly."  This is as close as I can get in a couple of lines.

Answer (score 7):

A mild refactoring of ubpdqn's code:

```
f[n_, d_] := #*Map[{-Cos[#], -Sin[#]} &, #/d] & @ Sqrt @ Range @ n

di[n_, d_, rad_] :=
  Module[{fu, pt, grad, pg},
    fu = f[n, d];
    pt = MapIndexed[{Disk[#, rad], Sqrt[HoldForm @@ #2] ~Style~ Black ~Text~ #} &, fu];
    grad = Reverse[{{0, 0}, ##} & @@@ Partition[fu, 2, 1]];
    pg = MapIndexed[{Hue[#2/n], Polygon @ #} &, grad];
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], pg, White, pt}]
  ]

di[87, 0.4, 0.5]
```

Comment: nice...always can do better...did not realise was duplicate

Answer (score 6):

I nest the right turns with `# + Normalize@Cross[#] &`. Since [2012rcampion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/21750/2012rcampion) has rather solved the coloring, here's a version using a close match from one of *Mathematica*'s gradients.

```
cf = Lighter[ColorData["AvocadoColors", 1. - #], (1. - #)^8] &;
With[{npts = 87},
 Graphics[
  GraphicsComplex[
   NestList[# + Normalize@Cross[#] &, {1., 0.}, npts - 1] ~Append~ {0., 0.},
   {EdgeForm[Thin],
    Table[{cf[i/npts], Polygon[{i, i + 1, npts + 1}]}, {i, npts - 1, 1, -1}], 
    Table[{White, Disk[i, 1/3], Black, Text[HoldForm[Sqrt[#]] &@i, i]}, {i, npts}]}
   ],
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> Scaled[0.1/Sqrt[npts]]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wow!  The use of `Cross` is very clever, and `GraphicsComplex` is a nice touch to keep it clean.